# Where exactly do radians come from?

Tags: angle

I'm aware that the angle in radians is 1 when the arc length is equal to the radius. However, I wonder if this is exactly where radians come from. Have we set radians like this (like we set $i^2$ to $-1$) or is there something more to it?

Comment: Amongst other things, the derivatives of the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions become *much* easier when the arguments are radians rather than degrees or other unit.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](https://jeff560.tripod.com/r.html), the term "radian" was coined independently
by James Moore and William Thompson (Lord Kelvin) in the 19th century.